# How can i write a shell script to display the below output? 1

Tags: shell

In shell script a command output gives integer number like :

```
xxx$> xxxx
10
20
30
```

I want to add those integer values and get sum value. What is the simplest way to do..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing your script is named `xxxx`, you could do :

```
xxxx | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'
```

Which would print the sum of the integers printed by `xxxx` :

```
~$ xxxx
10
20
30
~$ xxxx | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
60
```